# What is the probability that a permutation of the numbers $\{1,2,3, \dots, n\}$ has at least two fixed points?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Regarding this question:

> What is the probability that a randomly selected permutation of $\{1,2,3, \dots, n\}$ has at least two indices $j$ such that $\pi(j)=j$?

I though about the following solution:

First pick those two numbers to be fixed points, there's $\binom{n}{2}$ options for that. Then, multiply that with the number of permutations of $(n-2)$ numbers, and finally divide by the probability space.
Then:

$$ Pr(A)=\frac{\binom{n}{2}(n-2)!}{n!} = \frac{1}{2}$$

This is the correct answer.
But then I thought: doesn't it count the same permutations more than one time? (double counts).

Let's examine the following example:

I chose the numbers $1$ and $2$ to be the fixed points, and let the others arrange.
One of the arrangements is $1,2,3,4,5$.
In a different cast, I choose $4$ and $5$ and let the others arrange, and once again counted $1,2,3,4,5$ as a valid option.

How does it settle?

Thanks

Comment: What's the probability of no fixed points? Exactly one fixed point?

Comment: "This is the correct answer." No it is not (so your doubt is justified). If $n=3$ then the probability is $\frac16$. Are you familiar with [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown at least two points.

Comment: @drhab this is the official exam solution :)

Comment: @superuser123 The correct answer isn't $1/2$. You are right that it double-counts, so cannot be correct. By the way, did you think about my hint?

Comment: I am totally confused right now. How can my lecturer be wrong about that? Does it help if I say that the probability is uniformly distrubuted?

Answer (score 3):

There are $n!$ permutations.

There are $!n$ permutations without a fixed point, they are so-called derangements.

To find the number of permutations that have exactly one fixed point we start by fixing one ($n$ possibilities) and end with $n\times!(n-1)$ possibilities.

Our final conclusion is that the number permutations having at least $2$ fixed points is:$$n!-!n-n\times!(n-1)$$

This leads to probability:$$\frac{n!-!n-n\times!(n-1)}{n!}$$

If you are not familiar with notation $!n$ then have a look at [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Also there you find other expressions for $!n$.

Comment: I have rephrased the question, maybe it's more clear now?

Comment: Yes. it is clear and agrees with my interpretation of the first version.

Comment: Thanks, I will check this once again.